# State didn't change in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have this reducer that has in initial state and array of plans that has array of visits that has an array of treatments.
The idea is when action (Remove_treatment) is triggered, it removes one of the treatment as following:

```
import { REMOVE_TREATMENT } from "./treatmentPlanTypes";

const initialState = {
  plans: [
    {
      id: 1,
      visits: [
        {
          id: 1,
          treatments: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "treatment1",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "treatment2",
            },
          ],
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          treatments: [
            {
              id: 1,
              name: "treatment1",
            },
            {
              id: 2,
              name: "treatment2",
            },
          ],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

const treatmentPlanReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REMOVE_TREATMENT:
      let clonePlans = [...state.plans];

      const visitIndex = clonePlans[0].visits.findIndex(
        (i) => i.visitId === action.visitId
      );

      const treatmentIndex = clonePlans[0].visits[
        visitIndex
      ].treatments.findIndex((i) => i.treatmentId === action.treatmentId);

      clonePlans[0].visits[visitIndex].treatments.splice(treatmentIndex, 1);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(clonePlans));
      return {
        ...state,
        plans: [...clonePlans],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

When I console.log(clonePlans) I get the correct array.

But when I return the value like:

return {
...state,
plans: [...clonePlans],
};

I'm still having the old plan and not updated in the component.
If I tried to enter the expected plan as I get from console.log directly in the above return statement, the component is updated successfully.

this is a part of the component in my code:

```
  const plans = useSelector((state) => state.treatmentPlan.plans, shallowEqual)
  const listOfPlans = plans.map((plan) => (
    <PlanArea key={plan.planId} visits={plan.visits} />
  ));
  console.log(listOfPlans);
```

The component is still showing the old plan, but console.log(listOfPlans) shows the correct array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You need to deeply copy your plans array for your component to feel the change in state, and hence re-render*

```
let clonePlans = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(state.plans))
```

- 

```
return { ...state, plans: clonePlans };
```

Comment: I tried to do the splice in the component and send the updated plan to redux. but still same issue, some how the state is updated but the component doesnt re-render

Comment: You're right in concept, but constantly stringifying and unstringifying data is going to be a big bottleneck.  Better to just follow their own paradigm and either write their own function that will deeply reduce or use [Normalizing State Shape](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/normalizing-state-shape/).

Comment: @zero298 Yes 100% ...  stringifying and unstringifying is not the best approach (in terms of performance) for deeply copying a nested-array especially for big data .... But it's just an example to demonstrate the idea...